# Transform string in list of objects based in delimiter character

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-transform

I'm trying to transform a string that i got from a base64 decrypt.

Something like:

"user@123#age@35#email@user123@gmail.com"

In:

> [ {user: "123", age: 35, email: "user123@gmail.com"} ]

Comment: Why is the result in an array? Is the array always going to contain one element and one element only?

Comment: How do we know that `user` is supposed to be a string and not a number?  What if any of your values has the `#` character in it; is it escaped in some way?  How does this have anything to do with base64?  I'm wary of any "deserialize this string" task that doesn't have explicit rules describing how it was serialized in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Split by `#`, reduce the pairs onto a `Map`, convert into an object.

```js
const splitOnFirst = (str, sep) =>
  (index => index < 0 ? [str] : [str.slice(0, index), str.slice(index + sep.length)])
  (str.indexOf(sep));

const parseHash = (hash, mapper = {}) =>
  Object.fromEntries(hash.split('#').reduce((map, pair) =>
    (([k, v]) =>
      map.set(k, mapper[k] ? mapper[k](v) : v))
    (splitOnFirst(pair, '@')), new Map));

console.log(parseHash('user@123#age@35#email@user123@gmail.com', { age: Number }));
```

### Output

```json
{
  "user": "123",
  "age": 35,
  "email": "user123@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: Email key is not showing proper value